# PHP Javascript T_VAR

Tags: javascript, php

I'm attempting to extract lat/long points from MySQL to eventually plot them in Leaflet using Javascript. I ran the following PHP code (planelatlong.php) and got an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) on line 24.

I looked at similar errors on Stack Overflow for `T_VAR`, but couldn't find a clear solution for my issue.

Code:

```
<?php
    $username = "stackoverflow"; 
    $password = "thanksstackoverflow";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="homedb";
    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $myquery = "SELECT  'lat', 'lon' FROM  'test01';
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);
    if (!$query) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }
    $data = array();
    echo "var planelatlong = [";
    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        echo "[",$data[$x]['lat'],",",$data[$x]['lon'],"]";
        if ($x <= (mysql_num_rows($query)-2) ) {
            echo ",";
        }
    }
    echo "];";
    mysql_close($server);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to end double quote at line 13. Use below line

```
 $myquery = "SELECT  'lat', 'lon' FROM  'test01'";
```